# Reopening AWS Account after closing more than 90 days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I created an AWS Account in 2 years ago. After some time the account was hacked and I talked to customer support and closed the account. Now, I wanted to open AWS account again.

I tried logging in but the dashboard says "No such account exists". I tried signing up again which sends verification code to my gmail account except the mail says that an account is already there hence I should login. After I click the login link, I'm redirected back to Login Console which says no such account exists.

How do I actually create an AWS account now?

Answer (score 6):

I sent an email to AWS Support. They told me the following:

"your account was closed more than 90 days ago, after the Post-Closure Period we will not be able to re-open the closed account. Please note that the email address registered to an AWS account at the time of the account closure cannot be used to create a new AWS account, however there is a workaround that we can use.

if your email is (myemail@gmail.com) and you add any of these symbols { + ; - ; * . ) or similar type symbols to your email so that it looks like this (myemail+@gmail.com), you will be able to create a new AWS Account and have access to Free Tier for 12 months."